# Why the "sizeof" operator can get the size of a type?

Tags: c++, sizeof

For example:
A complex class

```
class complex
{
public:
   complex(double r = 0, double i = 0)
      : re(r), im(i) {}
   complex &operator += (const complex &);
   double real() const { return re; }
   double imag() const { return im; }
private:
   double re, im;
};
```

I can get the size of complex by:

```
complex c(1, 2);
cout << sizeof(c) << endl;
```

But why I can also get the size of the complex by:

```
cout << sizeof(complex) << endl;
```

I didn't instantiate a complex object. How does the computer know the actual size of complex without creating an object to test it?

I don't believe that the compiler contains all data type length information for different bits of OS. And the program can allocate memory for 'long' type differently on 32bit or 64bit OS. There must have a way to decide data length on run-time.

Comment: Compiler _has_ to know what a type looks like in memory.

Comment: Because it was designed to work that way. See [C11 6.5.3.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4). *Question was originally tagged C*

Comment: Size of `class complex` type is known at the compilation time. It is not calculated at run time in this case.

Comment: The size of **any** type in C++ is known at compile time.

Comment: @Evg any complete type

Comment: I want to know if the compiler knows the length of a type without instantiating an object of the type, how can the program layout the memory on different computers? How does the program adjust the length of the integer to 4 bytes instead of 2 bytes? Who told the compiler the data length information?

Comment: Please don't tell me that It has always been so.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes. Thanks for a correction.

Comment: A program doesn't adjust anything. The size of `int` is known at the moment when code is being compiled. A compiler is programmed that way.

Comment: @Evg You mean the compiler knows the all data length on all computers? It's not possible. There must be some way it acquired how many bytes an integer has.

Comment: A compiler doesn't work on all computers. It works on a fixed set of computer architectures, often just one.

Comment: Ok, then how the compiler tells the difference of integer size on 32bit and 64bit OS?

Comment: A compiler knows what architecture it compiles for. A 32-bit architecture gets 32-bit types. A 64-bit architecture gets 64-bit types.

Comment: [gcc options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html): *The `-m32` option sets `int`, `long`, and pointer types to 32 bits, and generates code that runs on any i386 system. The `-m64` option sets `int` to 32 bits and `long` and pointer types to 64 bits, and generates code for the x86-64 architecture. ...*

Comment: If I want to **new** an integer on a 32-bit architecture, 4 bytes of memory will be allocated, on a 64-bit architecture, 8 bytes of memory will be allocated. How does the new operator decide the length of integer on run-time?

Comment: Syntactical note, you can write `int x; auto x_sz = sizeof x;` which does not need parens (`sizeof` is not a function) for a **variable** or **expression** (a complex expression may need parens, since sizeof is minimally greedy), or `auto int_sz = sizeof(int)` which requires the parens for a **type**.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to understand this is to look at the [generated assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/bxeoPW4fr).  See how it is completely different for different platforms? See one has a little 8 embedded in it, and the other has 4? That's the size of `long` on their respective platforms.

Comment: @ZhenYang `new` doesn't make that decision. The compiler generates code that tells `new` how much to allocate. The compiler knows how large an `int` is for the architecture it is generating code for. An executable doesn't run on multiple architectures, only on the one architecture it is compiled for. If you want code that runs on multiple architectures, you need to run the compiler multiple times (or even use multiple compilers) to generate a different executable for each architecture.

Comment: This is a well-written question. It may rely on a false assumption about the C++ type system, but that assumption is clearly stated and this post is clear, genuine, and self-contained. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects of type `complex` are all of same size, hence you don't need to create an object to know its size.

`sizeof(x)` is a constant expression. It is not evaluated at runtime. A class definition is necessary and sufficient for the compiler to know the size of objects of that type. Thats also the reason you cannot use `sizeof` with an incomplete type (declared but not defined). And the compiler is using that information all the time, when you pass a `complex` by value to a function, when you create an object of type `complex`, etc.

The size of a type is the size of its members plus padding. For more details I refer you to [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member).

Comment: this should be comment!

Comment: @Uttam as I understand the question, this answers the question, hence should not be a comment.

Comment: Thanks 463025818, I just want to know how the compiler gets the data length information without actually creating an object to test it.

Comment: @ZhenYang its the size of members + this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member

Comment: @ZhenYang the compiler needs to know the size of the object in order to be able to generate the code that creates the object. This should be obvious when the object is created dynamically using `new`. Behind the scene, `new` allocates memory for the object it creates and it needs to know the size of the object to know how much memory to allocate.

Comment: @axiac Yes, it should be. I'm curious about who told the compiler the data size information. Is it the OS? I assumed that the compiler creates all the basic data types (int, char, float ...) on the sneak to get the actual size on different computers (Windows or embed, 32bit or 64bit).

Comment: @ZhenYang the size data originates within the compiler.  This means that, for instance, if you compile with GCC for 64-bit Linux, the binary you get will not work at all on 32-bit Windows.

Comment: @ZhenYang "*who told the compiler the data size information*" - the programmer(s) who made the compiler. It knows the CPU architecture being targeted, so it knows which size to use for native types like integers, as well as alignment padding, etc. That it all it needs to calculate the size of any type. It needs to know the size of any type in order to create it. "*Is it the OS?*" - no, and besides, multiple OSes can run on the same architecture. A compiler targets both an architecture (to generate the code that runs on the CPU) and an OS (to generate the metadata needed to run the code)